# I work at the store target, and the brands within target support and give money to israel should i quit?

Tags: halal-haram, sin

I work in the food department at target which contains a lot of brands that support and give money to israel, apart of my job is to put these products on the shelves, i don’t buy these products but i help put them out, should i quit my job?